# How to create promises from asynchronous tree structured APIs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, promise

## How to wait for indeterminate recursive promises to resolve

I am having issues with flow-control in my app. I have a hierarchical (family-like?) data structure, something like:

`{name: "Bob", children: [{name: "Tim", children: [..]}, {another child..}]}`

This structure can be many levels deep.

Now what I am trying to do is recursively iterate over all people, grab their ID, make api call to retrieve picture for this person.

Psuedo code:

```
gatherPicture(hierarchy);
console.log("I want to wait before doing this!") // Logs too early
function gatherPicture(person) {
    // api request (promise)
    getPicture(person.id).then(r => {
        person.picture = r;
        person.children.forEach(gatherPicture);
    }) 
}
```

Hopefully that code makes sense. How do I get my code to wait until gatherPicture function has handled and resolved all people?

If it adds anything, I am using AngularJS and do have access to the $q promise service available. But I just don't understand how to setup this particular chain of promises because they are built inside of a recursive function.

Thanks very much!

Comment: The structure is called a *tree*

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50519124/633183

Comment: The answers here use generic ES6 promises. Keep in mind that ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Use `$q.all` with the AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to use `$q.all` and `Array.prototype.map`

```
gatherPicture(hierarchy)
.then(() => {
    console.log("I want to wait before doing this!")
})

function gatherPicture(person) {
    // api request (promise)
    return getPicture(person.id).then(r => {
        person.picture = r;
        return  $q.all(person.children.map(gatherPicture));
    }) 
}
```

So first of all return the Promise chain you start with `getPicture` from your `gatherPicture`, so that you can build up a proper Promise chain.

Then next thing is that you create a list of Promises for all children using `person.children.map(gatherPicture)` and you then wait for it to resolve using `Promise.all`

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that it is important to use .map in this situation to properly chain these.

Comment: @Summy an additional note, this approach has one downside, it will start initial the downloads of of all children at _"the same"_ time (JavaScript is not multi threaded) but the downloads can be.

Comment: @Summy you might want to try it with AngularJS's version: `$q.all()`

Answer (score 0):

```
gatherPicture = (person) => {
    getPicture(person.id)
    .then(data => {
        person.picture = data;
        return Promise.all(person.children.map(gatherPicture));
    }) 
}
```

Comment: The answer here uses generic ES6 promises. Keep in mind that ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Use `$q.all` with the AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to first flatten the tree:

```js
const flatten = (tree) => (tree.children || [])
  .reduce((flattened, child) => flattened.concat(flatten(child)), [])
  .concat(tree);
```

Then, given a simple `gatherPicture` function:

```js
const gatherPicture = (person) => getPicture(person.id).then((picture) => {
  person.picture = picture;
});
```

You can easily wait for them all to be finished, **concurrently**:

```js
const gatherPictures = (tree) => Promise.all(flatten(tree).map(gatherPicture));
```

Use:

```js
gatherPictures(hierarchy).then(() => {
  console.log("Done");
});
```

Comment: The answer here uses generic ES6 promises. Keep in mind that ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Use `$q.all` with the AngularJS framework.